# Why is $f^n(\xi(x))$ continuous over $x$?

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

> Why is this function continuous over $x$?
>
> $$f^{n}(\xi(x))=\frac{-(n!\left(-f(x)+f(x_{0})+f(x_0)(x-x_0)+\ldots+\frac{f^{n-1}(x_0)*(x-x0)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\right)}{(x-x_0)^n}$$

I tried solving it via the *Heine sequence criteria*, but to no avail. I need someone help me with the explanation for this, please!

Could the answer be, that since the left side of the equation is the final remainder of a *Taylor series* and a *Taylor series* converges to a certain function, then that remainder would ideally converge to zero?

Comment: The left side is continuous in $x$ because the right side is. Note that $\xi(x)$ alone need not be continuous.

Comment: I was indeed pondering the continuity of the right hand side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Taylor formula with the integral form of the remainder term
$$
f(x)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+\ldots+\frac{f^{(n-1)}(x_0)(x-x_0)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}
\\
+\int_{x_0}^x\frac{f^{(n)}(s)(x-s)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}ds.
$$
Now substitute $s=x_0+t(x-x_0)$ in the remainder term to get
$$
\int_{x_0}^x\frac{f^{(n)}(s)(x-s)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}ds=(x-x_0)^n\int_0^1\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0+t(x-x_0))(1-t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}dt
$$
to see that indeed the quotient is a continuous function as long as $f$ is $n$ times continuously differentiable.

Comment: in the function mentioned above by me, could it be also provable to be continuous by using the L'Hospital because at the limit $\lim_{x \to x_0} \text{right hand side}$ we get the uncertainty $\frac{0}{0}$. If so, then how?

Comment: though it might be because of me misunderstanding your answer, I don't see how your reasoning will help me solve this issue. I need to provide an answer to the question: Since the left hand side must be differentiable $n$ times, it must be continuous. The problem stems from the $(x-x_0)$ in the denominator. Is the right hand side still continuous at $x_0$ and why?

Comment: Sorry, in a previous idea I had found it useful to replace $x_0$ with $a$, this is now reversed. As is hopefully now clearer to see, the division can now be carried out directly, and what remains is an integral over a continuous function, which is again a continuous function.

Comment: but is the function also continuous at $x_0$?

Comment: can I solve this somehow via limit?

Comment: Yes, it is continuous everywhere. Limits would only add an additional frame around essentially the same computations.